# In rsyslog on ubuntu, how to configure udp and tcp tls

Tags: rsyslog

So I have rsyslog on an Ubuntu machine receiving log messages from another machine. The machine is sending tls on port 6514. I have another machine sending to this rsyslog server udp messages on port 514. Only the tls messages are getting to my /var/log/syslog file. The udp messages do not even though I do see the messages when I do a

```
sudo tcpdump port 514 -v
```

The related parts of my /etc/rsyslog.conf file are below

```
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/ca.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/xxx.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/rsyslog-keys/yyy.pem

$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
$ModLoad imtcp
$InputTCPServerStreamDriveAuthMode anon
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon
$InputTCPServerStreamDriverMode 1
$InputTCPServerRun 6514
```

What can I be missing that the udp messages are not getting to the syslog folder?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: tcpdump sees the data before iptables, so check you dont have a rule dropping udp on 514. Are you using SELinux? Run `rsyslogd -dn` in the foreground to a log file to see if it says anything about 514 udp. Beware, very verbose output, so limit all input but udp.

Comment: i tried iptables -L -n -v | grep -i DROP but don't see udp 514 in the list...also when i tried iptables -L -n -v | grep 514 i did not see any rule for udp 514 but I did see the rule for tcp 6514 and tcp 514...maybe I have to add a rule for udp 514 or do they get automatically generated when there is traffic? I will try rsyslogd -dn..thank you!

Comment: If you have a rule accepting tcp 514 or 6514, you will probably need to explicitly add a udp 514 rule too. I dont know of anything automatic that would add it.